# telegram.error.BadRequest: Message to edit not found

Tags: telegram, python-telegram-bot

What kind of event should trigger the functionality?

- A user presses an [InlineKeyboardButton](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.inlinekeyboardbutton.html) within the bot itself

What kind of chat is the functionality supposed to work in?

- The button is on a message that is from a bot to the user. (i.e inside chat with a bot. NOT in a group/channel)

How do you want your bot to react?

1. I wish to read the text of the message using text = str(update['callback_query']['message']['text'])
2. I then wish to edit that message using query.edit_message_text(text=text, reply_markup = keyboard)

**What is the problem?**

- In step 1, that 'text' field is completely missing in the 'Update' dictionary.
- As a result, the 'edit_message' in step 2 dont work and throw "Message to edit not found telegram"
- The above behavior occurs for posts about 48hours from today. Meaning the inlinebutton works normally first, then after ____ period of time passed, the error described above is observed.

What is my hypothesis?

- Telegram side deletes that information and dont allow me to call it after ____ period in time.

Comment: The notes I made in the ptb user group still apply ;) https://t.me/pythontelegrambotgroup/487870?thread=487626

Comment: Hi Stag, thank you for replying (both on tele and here). Sorry I've not gotten the time to create a minimum viable testing bot for the issue. E.g i'll prob have to wait 4 days for each change to see if it made a difference.

My current hot fix: To use the url function of the button to link the users instead of relying on callback function. There are several downsides to this approach but it suits my use case for now.